# Backend Registrations face group-based pricing (extension) selections

Tags: extension, groups, price-sets

https://github.com/zengenuity/civicrm_groupprice/issues/7

Does anyone have a creative work-around or fix for this? Basically, when we make a back-end registration, we want to see all price set fields/options, regardless of the group-based pricing. The staff member doing the registrations, as it currently stands, only sees price sets based on the groups they may or may not be a part of.

CiviCRM 4.7.x (sigh:I know)

It should be working, but isn't. The user has 'Administer CiviCRM' permission assigned to their role.

```
 // If the user is an admin, just put a message next to the "hidden" options.
  // Otherwise, really hide them.
  if ($hide) {
    if ($isAdmin) {
      $amount[$amount_id]['options'][$priceOption['id']]['label'] .= '<em class="civicrm-groupprice-admin-message"> (visible by admin access)</em>';
    }
    else {
      $removed = $amount[$amount_id]['options'][$priceOption['id']];
      unset($amount[$amount_id]['options'][$priceOption['id']]);
      if ($removed['is_default'] && !empty($amount[$amount_id]['options'])) {
        $amount[$amount_id]['options'][reset(array_keys($amount[$amount_id]['options']))]['is_default'] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: they have to be in the CiviCRM group 'Administrators' to see the price fields restricted by group.

This wasn't documented as far as I noticed...but obvious in the code. Thanks extension creator! /civicrm/group/search?reset=1&force=1&context=smog&gid=1